# Unity3d big video file issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making an android virtual tour application.
Inside my project i have a lot of 4k videos but the problem is that when i buid i recive this error:

```
"Android Asset Packaging tool filded"
```

---

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Android Asset Packaging Tool failed.
C:\Users\Ale\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.0-rc2\aapt.exe package -v -f -F raw.ap_ -A raw -0 "" --ignore-assets "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"

stderr[
ERROR: Zip flush failed, archive may be hosed
ERROR: packaging of 'raw.ap_' failed
]
stdout[
Found 1 custom asset file in raw
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  assets\bin\Data\sharedassets0.resource
    Src: () raw\bin\Data\sharedassets0.resource

Resource Dirs:
Creating 'raw.ap_'
Writing all files...
      'assets/bin/Data/sharedassets0.resource' (not compressed)
Generated 1 file
Included 0 files from jar/zip files.
Checking for deleted files
Removing raw.ap_ due to earlier failures
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.AAPTPackage.AAPTPack (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, System.String apkName, System.String directory, Boolean compress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.AAPTPackage.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

How can i solve this?
I can't optimize the videos more than this or remove a part of them... 
The app will only be used by me in the fairs so I do not care about the final weight that it will have.

thanks to those who will try to help me and sorry for bad english(:

Comment: Copy the error and post it. I don't think this is the complete error. Copy it like it is in the Editor then post it. If there are multiple error, also post them. Also post your Unity version. If you delete the video file, is the error still there?

Comment: if i delete the videos works. i update my post with the errors